# Date range or date with operation (greater than, etc.) contextual filter

Tags: views, datetime

I get date with contextual filter in views and i want set "greater than" my date. This option not exist in contextual filter. I cannot use argument in filter criteria.

In drupal 7 we can use "2017-01-01--2017-12-18" for range date with contextual filter, but in drupal 8, this trick not work.

Someone can help me, with date and contextual filter ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why we don't have operator (>=, <=, etc.) in contextual filter...

Temporary solution... affect all views with argument :

File :

\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\argument\Formula.php

Change :

```
$formula = $this->getFormula() . ' = ' . $placeholder;
```

to

```
$formula = $this->getFormula() . ' >= ' . $placeholder;
```

Function :

```
public function query($group_by = FALSE) {
    $this->ensureMyTable();
    // Now that our table is secure, get our formula.
    $placeholder = $this->placeholder();
    $formula = $this->getFormula() . ' >= ' . $placeholder; 
    $placeholders = [
      $placeholder => $this->argument,
    ];
    $this->query->addWhere(0, $formula, $placeholders, 'formula');
}
```